# How to send right and left cursor using Soda/Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, soda

I'm using `Soda` to run `Selenium Webdriver`.  Mostly it's working as expected but I'm trying to figure how to send the right and left cursor keys to the browser to move a jquery ui slider handle.

I tried

```
.typeKeys('css=a.ui-slider-handle[lr="l"]','\37')
```

and

```
 .type('css=a.ui-slider-handle[lr="l"]','\37')
```

and

```
.typeKeys('\37')
```

and

```
.type('\37')
```

Nothing seems to move the slider.  None of them error either.  I'm sending a click to the handle before I do this just to be sure...

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Working code in Java-

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/");
//Identify WebElement
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='slider']/a"));
//Using Action Class
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();
action.perform();
driver.quit();
```

Source - https://gist.github.com/2497551

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having a bit of trouble with the dragAndDrop action but guessing that's something to do with the accessor I'm using.  Might be a timing problem in that jquery hasn't done it's work yet before trying to do this.....will continue to investigate.  Anyway your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, I tested this in firefox with jquery UI slider page and it worked for me.

.clickAt("//div[@id='slider']/a[1]", "")

//mouse left key down

.mouseDownAt("//div[@id='slider']/a[1]", "0,0")

//move the cursor some 200 from left

.mouseMoveAt("//div[@id='slider']", "200,0")

//Release the mouse button

.mouseUpAt("//div[@id='slider']", "");